# Running executables iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, jailbreak

I'm trying to make an iOS app to run an executable file from code. The file is in `/usr/bin/`, and I need to execute it with arguments.

How can I do it?

Comment: This can only be done on jailbroken devices and it can't be done for apps meant for the App Store.

Comment: Thats fine, I have a jailbroken iPhone and I'm not going to publish it. so.. how can I do this

Comment: See the code fragment in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326684

Comment: @CuriousRabbit, (or JustSid) you should submit that as an **answer**.  That's a valid solution to this problem, but this question is not a duplicate of the other question because this is for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to call some command line applications using `NSTask` as described here:

[NSTask or equivalent for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536400/nstask-or-equivalent-for-iphone)

Including the NSTask.h header file from Mac OS X was enough to get this working on my jailbroken device.