# Launch executable using NSTask in sandbox on iOS?

Tags: ios, process

Is it possible technically and allowed by Apple for AppStore app to launch NSTask for an executable in sandbox on iOS?

Comment: This question is about NSTask permissions so it's not the same question

Comment: And [here is another, duplicate question (with answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536400/nstask-or-equivalent-for-iphone) that talks about NSTask use under iOS.